# Are there any weekend-only tourist activities in Hong Kong?

Tags: children, hong-kong, weekends

My family and I will be visiting Hong Kong in December, and will be doing some of the tourist stuff such as Disneyland, museums, shopping and eating. Because Hong Kong is such a crowded city, we would prefer to do a lot of these activities on a weekday, hoping it will be less crowded.

Which leaves us wondering: is there anything to do or anyplace to go that we should do during the weekends? (For example, a lot of cities have Saturday or Sunday-only outdoor night markets.)

My daughter is only 11 years old, so visiting the racetracks is probably not a good idea. (Besides, none of us are interested in watching horse-racing.)

Comment: I don't know Hong Kong but the horse racing is extremely family oriented in Seoul, South Korea - something that really surprised me compared to Australia where I'm from where it's mostly old men with red noses who wear hats at the races unless there's some special event on like the Spring Carnival or Melbourne Cup.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but my impression of horse racing in Hong Kong is that it is mostly an excuse to do gambling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was in Hong Kong recently and there was nothing that appeared to be 'weekend only'. I didn't see any change in how crowded things were at weekends compared with weekdays. Hong Kong is always incredibly crowded.

We did try to visit the Hong Kong Museum of History  on a Tuesday and found that it was closed every Tuesday. (It is well worth it, by the way - we came back a different day) You might find that other museums have a 'closing day' too.

Answer (score 1):

One thing that is fun is going to the [10,000 Buddhas temple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_Thousand_Buddhas_Monastery):

It requires a bit of a walk and is therefore off-limits for tourist buses. There are many Buddha statues with funny faces along the way, the view is great from there, they have a vegetarian restaurant that serves quite good food which visually and taste-wise imitates classic Chinese dishes (sweet & sour chicken for example).
Another thing is going to Sai Kung and eating at one of the many [Seafood restaurants](https://www.google.com/search?q=sai%20kung%20seafood%20restaurants&client=firefox-a&hs=16c&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=zxF7UrEVxvmQBdv5gKAL&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1467&bih=706). It's a bit of a way out, but the village is quite cute, there is another temple and the seafood restaurants are a real spectacle with their huge aquariums and live fish to pick from.

A walk down Hollywood road, seeing the Antique stores and the Mo Man Temple is also something more relaxed.

Comment: The OP was asking for weekends-only activities, but I'm fairly sure I've been to the 10,000 Buddhas and eaten at Sai Kung on weekdays...?

Comment: @jpatokal I understand that OP wanted to know things that are not overcrowded on weekends (see first paragraph). Ocean park is. Wong Tai sin is. The places I mentioned are not.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear enough. I'm looking for things to do that's is only available on weekends, regardless of the size of crowds. (We do intend to visit either Cheung Chau or Tai-O for some seafood. Thanks for the suggestion.)